# Updating version of SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, updating

I am currently running SQL Server 2008 Management Studio (version 10.0.1600.22) and I want to update due to a bug in this version.

All the documentation I have found so far has been for updating to SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio and SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express which I believe are different. Is that right?

I have also found links for updating SQL Server which I once again believe isn't what I'm looking for as I only want to update the client side.

Is there a way (or link) where I can update SQL Server 2008 Management Studio without having to reinstall it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the management tools for SQL Server 2008 R2 is backwards compatible with SQL Server 2008.

If you want to keep your database instance SQL Server 2008, just run the setup on the installation DVD and choose Maintenance -> Repair.  At the screen to select the instance, there is an option to select "Repair shared features only".  I don't have SQL Server 2008 DVD, only 2008 R2 DVD, but I believe the 2008 version works the same way.

Or if your computer doesn't have SQL Server database instance, you can do a fresh installation and choose only management tools.  Example screen shots (for 2008 R2): http://it-n-careerz.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-install-sql-server-management.html

Good luck!